# How to identify who is referencing an object in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, dealloc, retaincount

Is there any way to find, who is referencing an object in objective C?

I have a scenario where I'm expecting an object to have retain count as zero but is is greater than zero. I have no clue at that point what other objects are referencing it. I might have missed somewhere to remove reference, If there is any way to find it out I can take care of de-referencing those objects.

I'll appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Did you use Instrument's Leak tool?

Comment: You shouldn't use `-retainCount` to identify or diagnose memory management issues. See http://sdarlington.github.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no. You can use Clang's static analyzer (available as the "Analyze" build option in Xcode); it may be able to detect the places where you failed to free an object.

Comment: The Instruments Allocation tool is another useful tool for these scenarios.